# React Native Expo / Firebase security

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, expo, firebase-security

What all security measure I should take to make sure my API keys and firebase config information remains safe in my app.

Currently my firebase firestore DB rule is `allow read, write: if true;` should I change it to something else ? My app does have anonymous user authentication.

Are there any other security measures I should take ?

Comment: The configuration data of Firebase is not a security mechanism. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public. For how to secure access, see this answer that I just wrote: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969299/firestore-security-for-non-authenticated-access

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore Security for non-authenticated access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969299/firestore-security-for-non-authenticated-access)