# Firestore Security for non-authenticated access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm building a little learner project where I would like to use Firestore to store content that would displayed to my site. I'd like any user to be able to be able to access this information without needing to sign in. (I just use a simple: `allow read: if true` rule on the relevant collections.) This triggers an 'insecure rules' warning from Firebase. So, my question is, is this setup a bad idea that opens security risks? if so, what should I do....different rule setup, or should I look at a completely different db solution?

Some additional info:

Essentially, my project is kind of like a blog, where I'd like to store data on a database, which can then be viewed (but not edited) by any user without needing to sign in.

The amount of data that I'm storing is tiny. I'm using Firestore because I want to create a system where an administrator can go in and edit the content to be displayed to the site, without needing to redeploy the entire thing.

EDIT, here are my firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      
      allow write: if request.auth.uid=='unique id'
      allow read: if false;
    }
    match /quizPreview/{preview} {
        allow read: if true;
    }
    match /review/{review} {
        allow read: if true;
    }
    
    match /review/{review}/quizData/{quiz} {
        allow read: if true;
    }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There are *a lot* of Firebase/Firestore databases out there that fail to secure their data. Then over time the amount of data grows, and it often includes personally identifiable information (PII) at some point. But by then, many developers don't think of (securing) their data anymore, leaving their users at risk. And while you may think this won't happen to you, so did most of the developers of those other databases.

My recommendation is always the same: **your security rules should only allow the access that your code absolutely requires**.

So if you have a collection `blogs` in the database that the code needs to read, the first step would be to only allow read permission on `blogs` instead of on the entire database.

Next step is to think if the code really reads all blog post documents, or only a subset of them. If it only reads a subset of the documents, consider if you can capture that logic in security rules too.

Then do the same for the data in each document: does the application display each field? If not, should it really have access to all those fields? Consider if you can move some fields to another collection, where the app can't (easily) read them.

Even just the first step will stop the alerts from Firebase from coming, but more importantly: each of these steps makes your data more secure from intruders.

Comment: Appreciate this, I do limit access only to specific questions, but it still sends me a security warning.

Comment: If you have a concrete problem, please post a new question with the [minimal rules, and code with which we can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).