# Why does Firebase still saying I have to change security rules, even if I changed them three days ago

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I changed security rules to:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
          allow read;
          allow create: if isMine() && hasTimestamp();
  allow update: if isMine() && hasTimestamp() && isCalm();
  function isMine() {
    return request.resource.id == request.auth.uid;
  }
  function hasTimestamp() {
    return request.resource.data.timestamp == request.time;
  }
  function isCalm() {
    return request.time > resource.data.timestamp + duration.value(20, 's');
  }
    }
  }
}
```

But Firestore still sends me emails, that I must change security rules, or my database will be denied in 2 days. What rules I must add more? Thank you.

Comment: This is a better question for Firebase Support https://firebase.google.com/support

Comment: You still have unsecure rules. Your reads also should be secured.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB That sounds like an answer! 

Comment: Yes, but I want from non authenticated user's to see web content.

Comment: @Simon: That is a valid requirement. You'll either have to [explicitly grant the user access to the collections that your application code uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969299/firestore-security-for-non-authenticated-access/65969942#65969942) (instead of the blanket access you do now), or you can [disable the alert in the Firebase console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388991/stop-firestore-warning-that-everyone-can-read-data/55389780#55389780.

Comment: I rather do something, ,,better safe than sorry". But I have only one collection, so changing reads only to one collection is uselles.

Answer (score 0):

With my research and own experiance, I can tell, why Firebase keepeed sending warnings, that I have to fix insecure rules.
Well, after you'll apply strong rules, **wait for two - even three days.** Firebase has alert saying it will take max 24 hours.
For inspiration, here are my very basic sec. rules, that you can find in docs:

```
allow read: if true;
allow write: if request.auth != null;
```